# Why use cpio for initramfs?

Tags: compression, cpio, initramfs

I am making my own initramfs following the [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs). Instead of the familiar `tar` and `gzip`, the page is telling me to use `cpio` and `gzip`. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) says that `cpio` is used by the 2.6 kernel's initramfs, but does not explain why.

Is this just a convention or is `cpio` better for initramfs? Can I still use `tar` and `gzip`?

Comment: IIRC you cannot use tar as initramfs (I don't post it as answer as I'm not 100% sure). BTW using Gentoo I find much easier to configure built-in initramfs rather then hand-made one.

Comment: @Maciej I just want to know how to do it :) Furthermore I'm seeing a big boot time improvement by using my own initramfs

Comment: You misunderstood me. The method I was talking about is by giving the kernel during configuration a spec file which files should be included in the initrd (including custom `/init` etc.) and kernel simply uses that one. I'm not taking about generating initramfs by genkernel or similar methods.

Comment: @Maciej That looks fun! I'll try it sometime.

Comment: Well. It's IMHO easier to set up and it autoupdates with kernel (so I don't need to remember to copy new files into initrd).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but as the initial ramdisk needs to be unpacked by the kernel 
during boot, cpio is used because it is already implemented in kernel code.

Comment: Be 100% sure.  [linux/init/initramfs.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=init/initramfs.c;hb=HEAD) unpacks a `cpio -H newc` archive.

Comment: @ephemient This is really something. If there is no more answer coming in a few days I'll accept that `cpio` is used as a convention and that we have to use `cpio`.

Comment: Any ideas why newc is the format chosen?

Comment: According to kernel documentation, cpio was implemented just for the sake of initramdisk, so they could have implemented any other format.

Answer (score 18):

Quoting `Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt`:

> ### Why cpio rather than tar?
>
> This decision was made back in December, 2001.  The discussion started
>   here:
>
> http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1538.html
>
> And spawned a second thread (specifically on tar vs cpio), starting
>   here:
>
> http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1587.html
>
> The quick and dirty summary version (which is no substitute for
>   reading the above threads) is:
>
> 1) cpio is a standard.  It's decades old (from the AT&T days), and
>   already    widely used on Linux (inside RPM, Red Hat's device driver
>   disks).  Here's    a Linux Journal article about it from 1996:
>
> http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1213
>
> It's not as popular as tar because the traditional cpio command
>   line tools    require _truly_hideous_ command line arguments.  But
>   that says nothing    either way about the archive format, and there
>   are alternative tools,    such as:
>
> http://freecode.com/projects/afio
>
> 2) The cpio archive format chosen by the kernel is simpler and cleaner
>   (and    thus easier to create and parse) than any of the (literally
>   dozens of)    various tar archive formats.  The complete initramfs
>   archive format is    explained in buffer-format.txt, created in
>   usr/gen_init_cpio.c, and    extracted in init/initramfs.c.  All three
>   together come to less than 26k    total of human-readable text.
>
> 3) The GNU project standardizing on tar is approximately as relevant
>   as    Windows standardizing on zip.  Linux is not part of either, and
>   is free    to make its own technical decisions.
>
> 4) Since this is a kernel internal format, it could easily have been
>   something brand new.  The kernel provides its own tools to create and 
>   extract this format anyway.  Using an existing standard was
>   preferable,    but not essential.
>
> 5) Al Viro made the decision (quote: "tar is ugly as hell and not
>   going to be    supported on the kernel side"):
>
> http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1540.html
>
> explained his reasoning:
>
> http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1550.html
>      http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0112.2/1638.html
>
> and, most importantly, designed and implemented the initramfs code.

Comment: My only complaint with this answer is that the site no longer exists for the offered links to the Linux kernel mailing list. (Only just now realized that archive-stable links to Linux kernel mailing list items is probably a good idea.) A better(?) link to the first of the last three:  https://lkml.org/lkml/2001/12/22/132

Comment: Another possible political reason is that Redhat helps the Linux kernel development a lot.

Answer (score 3):

From what I remember of my old SysV days, cpio could handle dev files, but tar could not; this made cpio the 'raw' backup utility of choice before dump came around.  It was also easier to handle partial filesets and hard links so incremental backups were easier.  I think that GNU tar has caught up with cpio features so now it is just a matter of user comfortability.  Both cpio and tar should be installed by default.

Comment: `cpio` may be able to handle `tar`-format archives, and vice-versa in some cases, but that doesn't matter.  The kernel can only unpack `newc`-style `cpio`-format archives, which no `tar` I know of produces.

Comment: The format that GNU cpio incorrectly calls `newc` is officially named `asc` and of course supported by `star`.

Comment: @schily: That shows one of the implicit reasons quite nicely. "Well, it's some sort of tar archive. But which of the possible tar formats, and is it compatible with this tar extractor?" OTOH, cpio's version history is far less complicated.